# Sequences in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to track continuous number subsequences in MYSQL?

I want to count the highest continuous subsequences in the sequence of numbers:

```
1,2,3,4,6,7 => 4 (1-4)
1,2,3,4,5,6,8 => 6 (1-6)
1,2,3,5 => 3 (1-3)
1,2,3,5,6,7,8 => 4 (5-8)
1,2,4,5,6,8,9 => 3 (4-6)
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your question.  The text does not really make sense.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Arie could have explained his problem more detailed but it makes in the end sense.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII . . . They make sense if you look at the longest sequence (5, 6, 7, 8 and 4, 5, 6 respectively).

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks! I didn't see the 7 missing from last sequence

Answer (score 0):

According to your question this code should work:

```
function findHighestSeriesCount( $seriesArray )
{
    if ( 1 >= count( $seriesArray ) )
    {
        # catch the special case when array has only 0 or 1 element
        return count( $seriesArray );
    }
    $highestCount = -1;
    $currentCount = 1;
    $lastElement = $seriesArray [0];

    $getCorrectHighValue = function() use ( &$highestCount, &$currentCount )
    {
        return $highestCount < $currentCount ? $currentCount : $highestCount;
    };

    for ( $arrayIndex = 1 ; $arrayIndex < count( $seriesArray ) ; $arrayIndex++ )
    {
        if ( $lastElement + 1 == $seriesArray [$arrayIndex] )
        {
            $currentCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            $highestCount = $getCorrectHighValue();
            $currentCount = 1;
        }
        $lastElement = $seriesArray [$arrayIndex];
    }

    return $getCorrectHighValue();
}
```

Test script:

```
$seriesArray = [1,2,3,4,6,7];
echo sprintf( "array=%s - highest count=%d<br>", implode( ",", $seriesArray ), 
     findHighestSeriesCount( $seriesArray ) );

$seriesArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8];
echo sprintf( "array=%s - highest count=%d<br>", implode( ",", $seriesArray ), 
     findHighestSeriesCount( $seriesArray ) );

$seriesArray = [1,2,3,5];
echo sprintf( "array=%s - highest count=%d<br>", implode( ",", $seriesArray ), 
     findHighestSeriesCount( $seriesArray ) );

$seriesArray = [1,2,3,5,6,7,8];
echo sprintf( "array=%s - highest count=%d<br>", implode( ",", $seriesArray ), 
     findHighestSeriesCount( $seriesArray ) );

$seriesArray = [1,2,4,5,6,8,9];
echo sprintf( "array=%s - highest count=%d<br>", implode( ",", $seriesArray ), 
     findHighestSeriesCount( $seriesArray ) );
```

Output:

```
array=1,2,3,4,6,7 - highest count=4
array=1,2,3,4,5,6,8 - highest count=6
array=1,2,3,5 - highest count=3
array=1,2,3,5,6,7,8 - highest count=4
array=1,2,4,5,6,8,9 - highest count=3
```

Comment: This works fine but i want to do it in a query so i can sort them.

Comment: @Arie Aha, because you tagged the question with PHP I thought you are looking for a PHP code. May be you convert my code to a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is stored as a column, you can get the largest value by finding the longest consecutive sequence.  The idea is simply to subtract another sequence . . . where the values are constant, you know you have a sequence.

The rest is just aggregation.  This looks like:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      from t cross join (select @rn := 0) params
     ) t
group by (col - rn)
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: I try to use this query but does not understand what is meant by all.

I have a table with people and years and want to count the consecutive years and sort them

Comment: I have now:

`SELECT *, COUNT(id) FROM result WHERE pos = 1 GROUP BY user ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC`

Comment: @Arie . . . You should ask another question with appropriate data, desired results, and a description of what you are really trying to do.

Comment: @SteveD . . . `params` is a table alias for a subquery in the `FROM` clause.